# Chaining Rx interval and delay

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I started learning RxJS recently. I was experimenting with it a bit and came across following issue.

When chaining together delay and interval I would assume that each value will be emitted after (interval + delay) but this is not the case here. What's more strange to me is that when these two funcs are chained some values are printed at the same time without any delay. How should I understand it? What am I missing?

I'm using RxJS 5.0.3 and I was working in jsbin: https://jsbin.com/xoyuded/edit?js,console

This one:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(10).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

gives:

```
21:16:28.335 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 Console was cleared
21:16:29.757 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 0
21:16:30.756 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 1
21:16:31.756 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 2
21:16:32.756 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 3
21:16:33.756 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 4
21:16:34.751 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 5
21:16:35.755 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 6
21:16:36.751 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 7
21:16:37.751 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 8
21:16:38.751 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 9
```

This one:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(10).delay(1000).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

gives:

```
runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 Console was cleared
21:17:42.749 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 0
21:17:42.750 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 1
21:17:43.752 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 2
21:17:44.753 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 3
21:17:45.753 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 4
21:17:47.751 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 5
21:17:47.752 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 6
21:17:49.748 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 7
21:17:49.749 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 8
21:17:51.748 runner-4.0.2.min.js:1 9
```

Comment: Using the RxJS version and the code you posted, I don't see the behaviour you've described. In contrast to your console output, my repro using the second snippet emits values one second apart, with the first value emitted two seconds after subscription.

Comment: Thanks for take the time @cartant. I'm not sure what is an issue here. Maybe some inconsistencies in how timers work?

Comment: Can you post the jsbin?

Comment: @morganfree I just updated the question. Link to jsbin is now in the description.

Answer (score 1):

> When chaining together delay and interval I would assume that each value will be emitted after (interval + delay)

The assumption is wrong. Interval starts and after one second emits `0`. Delay then waits for another second, **but Interval doesn't stop**, so, after a total of 2 seconds, when Delay emits `0`, Interval is immediately ready to emit `1`, Delay takes a second then emits `1`, and `2` is immediately ready, so you get an initial 2s delay then one value every second:

- "2s 0"
- "3s 1"
- "4s 2"
- "5s 3"
- "6s 4"
- etc...

and this is exactly what your jsbin produces.

Comment: Thank you @Federico. This explains the first part. Now I see how they both work (interval + delay). What's is still missing for me is I can't figure out why some of numbers (eg 5, 6) were printed at the same time (see logs attached with the question). Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce it now in jsbin.

Comment: It's impossible to explain a behavior one cannot reproduce :) Maybe it was a some temporary issue.